# Checking to see if any character in a command line argument is not a '1' or a '0' in C

Tags: c, logic, command-line-arguments, control-flow

Part of a program I'm writing expects a binary number in a command line argument and returns its value as a decimal number. Part of the program checks to make sure the command line argument is an actual binary number (meaning it doesn't contain digits 2-9). This seemed relatively simple to implement, but for some reason this isn't working:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < strlen(argv[3] - 1); i++)
{
  if (argv[3][i] != '0' || argv[3][i] != '1' || argv[3][i] != '\0')
  {
    printf("arg[3][%d]: %c\n", i, argv[3][i]);
    printf("ERROR: argument 3 is not a binary integer\n%);
    return 0;
  }
}
```

(argv[3] is the argument where the binary value is supposed to go).

Even if I just give it the argument "0001", it will return:

"arg[3][0]: 0

ERROR: argument 3 is not a binary integer"

The rest of the code works fine, so I know it's just something obvious I'm not seeing about the logic in the if statement. Any help?

Comment: You need `&&` not `||`. And you want `strlen(argv[3])`. Otherwise you'll miss the last byte.

Comment: `argv[3] - 1` has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
if (argv[3][i] != '0' || argv[3][i] != '1' || argv[3][i] != '\0')
```

will always resolve to true. You should be using `&&` for AND rather than `||` for OR.

Additionally you had a bug with the `strlen(argv[3]-1);`. I'm guessing you actually meant `strlen(argv[3])-1;`, as the first one will be pointing to a bad location in memory. However you don't want the second one either as that will miss the last character.

The following is the code modified to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(argv[3]); i++)
    {
        if (argv[3][i] != '0' && argv[3][i] != '1' && argv[3][i] != '\0')
        {
            printf("arg[3][%d]: %c\n", i, argv[3][i]);
            printf("ERROR: argument 3 is not a binary integer\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. However, now it accepts correct input, but if i give it "121" it doesn't return the error message?

Comment: I modified my answer to include the entire code. This example when run will return the error message on 121 and not on 111.